# CodeFirst One to Many Viewmodel to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, code-first, one-to-many

using C#, VS2012, MVC4, CodeFirst

I've read tons of posts here and elsewhere about one to many with a viewmodel but I can't quite get it.

I have a program, AddressBook, with two tables, Name and Phone. For each name, you can have many numbers. Models below:

```
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class Name
    {
        public int NameID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        //ref
        public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class Phone
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }

        //ref
        [Required]
        public int NameId { get; set; }
        public Name Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and my context:

```
public class ContactDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Name> Names { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    }
```

My DetailViewModel:

```
public class DetailViewModel
    {
        public Name ID { get; set; }
        public Name FirstName { get; set; }
        public Name LastName { get; set; }

        public List<Phone> Number { get; set; }
    }
```

Now my controller, I start to get stuck. I'm able to call the list of Phone, but I seem can't get the isolated Name record.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            DetailViewModel dvm = new DetailViewModel();

            dvm.FirstName = (from n in db.Names select n).Where(m => m.NameID == id).ToString();
            dvm.LastName = (from n in db.Names where n.NameID == id select n).ToString();
            dvm.Number = (from n in db.Phones select n).Where(m => m.NameId == id).ToList();
            //tried a couple of different things

            return View(dvm);


            //Name name = db.Names.Find(id);
            //if (name == null)
            //{
            //    return HttpNotFound();
            //}
            //return View(name);
        }
```

User should be able to perform CRUD on Phone table once in the Details view for selected Name record. Phone CRUD can be completed on same or different page, whichever is easier to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I have not worked on phone development yet but it all comes to almost the same logic
try to use the Fluent API which you can read more about in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx)

now what you want to do is starting by making both of your classes **public** a lot of ppl working with this can forget it so that's why i have to say it but you have it already and thats good :)
so a name can have many numbers(phones?)

```
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class Name
    {
        public Name ()
        {
          PhoneList = new List<Phone>(); // just so you wont end up with a null reference if you have not yet provided any data.
        }
        public int NameID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        //ref
        public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }  //added the virtual
    }
}
```

now to your phone class

```
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class Phone
    {
        public Phone(){}
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }

        public virtual Name Name { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now on you OnModelCrating you can say what's required and what has many of what :) something like this

```
Protected override void OnModelCrateing(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  mobelbuilder.Entity<Name>().HasRequired<Phone>.(n=>n.ID).WithMany(n=>n.PhoneList).HasForeignKey(n=>n.NameID);
}
```

something this nice should be good :)

Have fun coding mate!

Cheers!

Comment: Oh, I was doing internet application development, not phone. But I actually want to do that a little later. Thanks for the answer; give me a few and I'll check it out in depth.

Comment: What I wrote is for web application : ) yea take your time. just tell me if my code worked for you or at least if it helped you!
Cheers!